# What is the main difference between asynctask and thread in android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Can you please tell me:

1. What the main difference between asynctask and thread is, in short one line ?
2. What are the respective advantages and disadvantages of Asynctask and Thread ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thread

```
1. A Thread is a Thread, probably you already know it from other part. You need to know that you cannot   update UI from a Thread. You need to use a Handler for this, but read further.
```

AsyncTask

```
2.  An AsyncTask is an intelligent Thread that is advised to be used. Intelligent as it can help with it's methods, and there are two methods that run on UI thread, which is good to update UI components.
```